# The Prolog code of the predicate intersperses an element on the n position of a list

Tags: prolog

title pretty much, if someone can help me with this exercice, it would be very helpful.

[image: Photo of my code that is not working]

Those are my clauses :

```
insereaza(L, Poz, Elem, Lrez):-lucru(L, Poz, Elem, Lrez),
    write(L).

lucru([], 0, Elem, [Elem]):-!.
lucru(L, Poz, Elem, Lrez):-
    Poz = 0,
    Lrez = [Elem|L].
lucru([H|T], Poz, Elem, Lrez):-
    N = Poz-1,
    lucru(T, N, Elem, Lnou),
    Lrez = [H|Lnou],!.
```

Query:

```
 insereaza([[vlad], [mihnea], [razvan]], 2, 1, [[vlad], [mihnea], [razvan]])
 lucru([[vlad], [mihnea], [razvan]], 2, 1, [[vlad], [mihnea], [razvan]])
```

Comment: You seem to want to compute the predecessor in `N = Pos-1`. That's will not work; you have to submit an order for explicit arithmetic evaulation: `N is Pos-1`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer changing that, shows me the same thing. [photo](https://i.imgur.com/LOFzGZr.png)